# powershell manifest import not working

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

I have written a small db query function and placed it into the file Query_SvcToSite.psm1.  I then created a manifest with the name Query_SvcToSite.psd1.  Both files are in my$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules folder
Get-Module -ListAvailable does not report the module or manifest.

In point of fact, the only way I can get the function to import is by specifying the full path to the .psm1 file.  Importing the manifest in this way does not make the function available.

After two days of trying different ideas from the web I am at a loss.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You put files to `WindowsPowerShell\Modules` or to `WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Query_SvcToSite`? What in your manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

> **Use the Correct Module Directory Name**
>
> A "well-formed" module is a module that is stored in a directory that has the same name as the base name of at least one file in the module directory. If a module is not well-formed, Windows PowerShell does not recognize it as a module.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

They will need to be in `$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Query_SvcToSite\` not just in the root of the Modules\ directory.